# File system causing c++ program to run slowly

Tags: c++

I am reading 1 million files from my local system (Ubuntu 20.04), about 10KB each. The first 40000 files are processed very quickly, and then the next 960000 are going at a much slower pace. I am assume this has something to do with the OS/Hardware/File System functionality. I am basically performing a file read as follows:

```
string read_file(std::ifstream& ifs) {
     vector<char> buf(64 * 1024);
     string s = "";
     ifs.read(&buf[0], buf.size());
     while (int n = ifs.gcount()) { s.append(&buf[0], n); ifs.read(&buf[0], buf.size()); }
     return s;
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening to cause this slow down and how it can be fixed?

EDIT: I am processing the strings in a function, I am not sure if they persist after execution:

```
 void process_file(string file_name) {
      ifstream ifs(file_name);
      string s = read_file(ifs);
      process_data(s);
 }

 void p1() {
      vector<string> files = get_files(); // 1 million size vector of filenames
      for (int i = 0 ; i < files.size(); i++) {
           process_file(files[i]);
      }
 }
```

process_data writes to another file but does not keep the string

EDIT: I have commented out the `process_data(s)` function and passed the `file_name` by reference and am getting the same behavior. However, if I run the program up to a number N, ctrl C, and then re-run, the first N files load very fast.

```
 void process_file(string& file_name) {
      ifstream ifs(file_name);
      string s = read_file(ifs);
      // process_data(s);
 }

 void p1() {
      vector<string> files = get_files(); // 1 million size vector of filenames
      for (int i = 0 ; i < files.size(); i++) {
           process_file(files[i]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: What do you do with the `string` returned from `read_file` - you don't keep it do you or do you process it immediately and get rid of it ?

Comment: Are these million files in one folder/subdirectory, or are they stored in multiple folders? Do they already exist or are they being created while you're reading earlier files?

Comment: Stored in a single directory, already exist before program execution.

Comment: Use a filesystem which uses b-trees for pathing, like **xfs** or **btrfs** (**btrfs** should be only used with modern kernels).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, are the files hosted on an ext4 filesystem or something else?

Comment: Can you split the files into multiple directories? Some file systems have performance issues accessing later files in large directories.

Comment: Quick elimination check: just remove the output step. You can easily see whether the problem is really the input, or the output, or the input & output interfering with each other.

Comment: 1 million files of 64k+ each > 64GB of RAM. The problem is probably that the writes to swap space are interfering with the reads.

Comment: "the first N files load very fast" -- because they are already cached. Disk access is much slower that buffered RAM access.

Comment: How can I cache select files? Is there a way to do this prior to program execution? The programmer should have some control over the cached file when performing data intensive applications like this, no?

Comment: "Caching" means loading it from disk. There are no shortcuts to reading data on disk. If it takes `X` seconds to read the data off disk, then it takes `X` seconds. What do you expect to gain by spending those `X` seconds before formally running your program, instead of after? It will still take the same total amount of time to accomplish the overall task, it makes no difference at all.

Comment: It is not just one kind of program which is needing to access these files but multiple other programs. It would be good to know which files are cache and which are not prior to execution so that execution is `n + X` and not `n * X` seconds, no?

Comment: The most recently written files are the ones that are most likely to still be cached.

Comment: Is there a way to know cached files on the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`string.append` is not the fastest. It will cause memory re-allocation. You could do:

- seekg 0 from end, then peekg, to get the file length.
- create a string and resize it to the needed length.
- in a loop, read directly into your string, by 64k blocks (or even read the whole file at once).

Comment: Don't seek to the EOF to get the file length.  Use the Linux `stat` or `fstat` function.  Seeking to EOF will cause more file accesses and slow the program.

Comment: The string should only be resized if the size of the file is larger than the current size of the string.

Comment: What's significant about 64k blocks?  What about 1M or larger?

Comment: That's a good point, but I don't think there's a portable C++ API to get file length.

Comment: @Jeffrey Doesn't `std::filesystem` have something exactly for this purpose? Pretty sure you can use [`std::filesystem::file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) or something to get the file-size in a portable way (or at least, as portable as C++ is concerned)